# Why is the \input command not honored when there is an incorrect use of \texttt before it?

Tags: input, typewriter

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
Foo
{ \texttt \input{bar.txt} }
Baz
\end{document}
```

This produces the output:

```
Foo bar.txt Baz
```

I was expecting this output instead:

```
Foo <content of bar.txt> Baz
```

where `<content of bar.txt>` contains the actual content of the file named bar.txt.

I understand that my code is incorrect and I know it can be fixed like this:

```
\texttt{ \input{bar.txt} }
```

or like this:

```
{\ttfamily \input{bar.txt}}
```

But I want to know why my incorrect code ended up producing the literal text `bar.txt` in the output instead of the content of the file bar.txt?

Comment: You probably want `{\ttfamily\input{bar.txt}}`

Comment: Just do `\meaning\texttt` to see where that argument ends up (which in your first case is just the same as `\texttt{\input}`).

Comment: @Manuel When I change the code to `{ \meaning\texttt \input{bar.txt} }`, I get this in the output: `Foo macro:-¿“protect “texttt Bar Baz`.

Comment: @Manuel If my code was interpreted as `\texttt{\input}` why do I not see the text `\input` appearing literally in the output?

Comment: @LoneLearner Sorry, but it doesn't work that easy, so forget it. I meant to show you a method to check yourself what happens and why things end up where they are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the braces around a TeX macro argument may always be omitted if the argument is a single token. `\fbox{a}` may be written `\fbox a`

so

```
\texttt \input{bar.txt}
```

is

```
\texttt{\input}{\bar.txt}
```

which is (modulo some checking not relevant here)

```
{\ttfamily \input}{bar.txt}
```

so a group starts, the font is switched  then TeX starts to process `\input`  it then inputs the file `.tex` which does nothing other than make a warning message that it does nothing. On the terminal you see

```
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/tools/.tex File ignored)
```

Then the `}` closes the group so no text is set in tt font. Finally the `{}` around `bar.txt` are taken as a group, not argument delimiters, and `bar.txt` is typeset in the document font.